# stochastic inventory question

Tags: optimization, references, operations-research

Does anyone have any references for inventory optimization? By optimizing I mean going from supplier to the allocation to the store.

I am doing research as to how to optimize any given inventory process. 
I have been looking at Stochastic processes, Bellman equations in Dynamic Programming and La Grange multipliers but have not found anything that is that helpful. I am just seeing if anyone has any ideas, do any theorems or algorithms come to mind?

I am just trying to gather some general information for personal research. 
I know this is a very vague question so please go easy on me lol.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just search for "inventory control"?  There are probably over 100 books out there, and many, many papers and on-line articles and presentations from classes of various levels.  If you want a book introduction to the field, try Axsater as an excellent intro + overview.

Comment: That actually seems like it may quite helpful. I have googled different inventory optimization methods and have not really found anything that has stuck out to me. I am not hugely mathematically inclined but do understand some higher level math. Thank you for the suggestion!